# How do I access an aliased column in the select query from my model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a chained query built which generates the exact query I need, but I am unable to access one of the key columns from any of my model objects. 
The example chain is as following:

```
Organization.select("bt.total_points total_points").
    includes(:current_summary).
    eager_load(:location).
    joins("JOIN #{Benefit.select("SUM(nen_score) as total_points, benefits.organization_id").
       group(:organization_id).as("bt").to_sql} ON bt.organization_id= organizations.id")
```

Here Organization has a one-many relation with Benefit model, one-one with location, ... 
Please do note, this chain will be further down have where clauses and order conditions appended to them, depending upon what the user selects.

I have tried using ***read_attribute*** *total_points* on the objects returned but I cannot find the column in any of the objects.

As requested the generated query, **(I have removed many a columns for brevity sake)**

```
SELECT  bt.total_points as total_points, 
        "organizations"."id" AS t0_r0,
        "organizations"."name" AS t0_r1,
        "organizations"."primary_role" AS t0_r5,
        "organizations"."founded_on" AS t0_r10,
        "organizations"."created_at" AS t0_r11,
        "organizations"."updated_at" AS t0_r12,
        "organizations"."city" AS t0_r13, 
        "organizations"."industry_id" AS t0_r15,
        "organizations"."location_id" AS t0_r16,
        "organizations"."summary_id" AS t0_r17,
        "locations"."id" AS t1_r0, 
        "locations"."name" AS t1_r1,
        "locations"."parent_id" AS t1_r2,
        "locations"."path" AS t1_r3,
        "locations"."created_at" AS t1_r4,
        "locations"."updated_at" AS t1_r5, 
        "organization_performance_snapshots"."id" AS t2_r0,
        "organization_performance_snapshots"."organization_id" AS t2_r1,
        "organization_performance_snapshots"."valid_from" AS t2_r2, 
        "organization_performance_snapshots"."valid_till" AS t2_r3,   
        "organization_performance_snapshots"."period" AS t2_r4,  
        "organization_performance_snapshots"."revenue" AS t2_r7, 
        "organization_performance_snapshots"."profit_after_tax" AS t2_r9, 
        "organization_performance_snapshots"."total_debt" AS t2_r11, 
        "organization_performance_snapshots"."created_at" AS t2_r14,  
        "organization_performance_snapshots"."updated_at" AS t2_r15 
FROM "organizations" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."id" = "organizations"."location_id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "organization_performance_snapshots" ON "organization_performance_snapshots"."organization_id" = "organizations"."id" AND (valid_till IS NULL) 
JOIN (SELECT SUM(nen_score) as total_points, benefits.organization_id 
    FROM "benefits" 
    GROUP BY "benefits"."organization_id") bt 
  ON bt.organization_id= organizations.id  
ORDER BY "organizations"."id" DESC
```

Comment: Can you show us the SQL that the query generates? Try adding `.to_sql` at the end.

Comment: @dgilperez Have added the generated query to the main question itself.

Comment: Have you tried to call `total_points` on the retrieved objects, instead of `read_attribute`? `organization = query.first; organization.total_points`

Comment: Yup, that's what I tried first. I just got back **nil** Tried inspecting the object and what not, but I couldn't see the value being stored anywhere.

Comment: Hmm I don't know what's going on, but are you sure there should be an actual value for that particular organization (it returns nil instead of giving a NoMethodError)? Also, I'd actually suggest to refactor the query to simplify that code and be able to detect the problem. At last, can you try moving the select to the last position?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't nil when I tried accessing it from the model object  _(undefined method 'total_points')_ I get nil when I try _"read_attribute"_ Shifting the _"select"_ call does not make any difference